# What's the best way to get top nth values from Dictionary?

Tags: c#, dictionary

I am trying to get the top *n* values from a dictionary. The part that is making it not easy for me is that if there are multiple values of the same rank, I need to keep all of them.
For example, if a dictionary looks like:

```
Dictionary<string, int> dict = new Dictionary<string, int>();
dict.Add("AAA", 91);
dict.Add("BBB", 97);
dict.Add("CCC", 98);
dict.Add("DDD", 92);
dict.Add("EEE", 97);
dict.Add("FFF", 100);
```

and if I want **Top 3**, I need to get

```
dict.Add("BBB", 97);
dict.Add("CCC", 98);
dict.Add("EEE", 97);
dict.Add("FFF", 100);
```

because BBB and EEE have the same rank. I first sorted the dictionary by the rank, and tried `Take()` but it only took one of the two.

```
/* Does not work */
var dictSorted = dict.OrderByDescending(x => x.Value).ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Value).Take(3);

/* The below only prints 
    FFF = 100
    CCC = 98
    BBB = 97

    but not  
    EEE = 97
*/
foreach(KeyValuePair kvp in dictSorted){
    Console.WriteLine(kvp.Key + " = " + kvp.Value);
}
```

Is there a good way to achieve this?

[Edit] Sorry about my question being unclear. What I wanted to mean was,
I need to keep the top 3 *different* ranks. If there are ties, all of them need to be included, but they are still within the same rank.

For example, if the candidates are:

100, 100, 100, 99, 99, 98, 98, 97, 97, 96,

then, I need 100, 100, 100, 99, 99, 98, 98 because these are top 3 *different* ranks. I am using dictionary because each rank is associated with a name like AAA, BBB, CCC.
Technically, in the above example, *top 3* would normally mean 100, 100, 100 and that's it, but in my case, it needs to be top 3 'different' ranks.

Comment: `.OrderByDescending(x => x.Value).Take(3)`?

Comment: I guess I didn't need the second half of that line of code.

Comment: @JeremyLakeman I removed the "ToDictionary...." and the code yields the same result, so I removed it. But it still does not keep the entries with the same rank. It only prints 3 entries.

Comment: The write your own `.Take` method to keep checking the subsequent elements for equality.

Comment: It sounds like you are using entirely the wrong data structure. You probably want a `SortedList` or similar. Dictionaries are a type of hash table, which does not have a guaranteed ordering

Comment: if 98 was there twice...youd get 5 elements...i dont know if you want top 3 and ties, or records with top 3 distinct values...unclear to me...if its 100 98 98 97 97 would you want the 97s or not?  the top 3 is 100 98 98, but the distinct top is 100 98 97

Comment: This Wikipedia page describes a number of ways to describe rankings when there are ties. I _think_ you want to keep all those with a "standard competition ranking" of N or less, is that right? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ranking

Comment: Sorry, now that I see why my question was unclear. I need to keep top 3 *different* ranks. If it is [100, 100, 98, 98, 98, 97, 96], I need 100, 100, 98, 98, 98 and 97 because these are top 3 *different* ranks. If a particular rank has ties, we need to include all of them too, but they are still within the *same* rank.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **grouping** with `GroupBy` method to include items with different `Key` but same `Value`s into result:

```
var kvpGroups = dict.OrderByDescending(x => x.Value).GroupBy(x => x.Value).Take(3);
```

Here you taking **NOT** first 3 `KeyValuePair`s, you taking first 3 **groups** of `KeyValuePair`s. Each group may contain one `KeyValuePair` if its `Value` was unique in source collection or may contain several `KeyValuePair`s if some of them has same `Value`s.

You can iterate groups with `foreach` in next way (`kvp` means `KeyValuePair`):

```
foreach (var kvpGroup in kvpGroups)
{
    foreach (var kvp in kvpGroup)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(kvp.Key + " = " + kvp.Value);
    }              
}

// Output:
// FFF = 100
// CCC = 98
// BBB = 97
// EEE = 97
```

Or LINQ version:

```
foreach (var kvp in from kvpGroup in (from kvp in dict
                                      orderby kvp.Value descending
                                      group kvp by kvp.Value into kvpGroup
                                      select kvpGroup).Take(3)
                    from kvp in kvpGroup
                    select kvp)
{
    Console.WriteLine(kvp.Key + " = " + kvp.Value);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't been entirely clear about the requirements, but I'm assuming you intend the common pattern where scoring competitors with no tie-breakers, where the top N qualify, and if there's a tie for Nth place then all those tied also qualify. So for example if you had [10, 10, 9, 9, 8, 8] then the top 3 would be [10, 10, 9, 9], because you have two 1st places, two 3rd places and two 5th places. Everyone at 3rd place and above qualifies. But if you have [10, 10, 10, 9, 9, 9] then only the 10s go through, because you have three 1st places and three 4th places - 4th place doesn't make the cut. Wikipedia calls this [standard competition ranking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ranking#Standard_competition_ranking_(%221224%22_ranking)).

There may well be a more elegant way to do it, but the straightforward way is to take the first n, and then also add on all those tied with the last one you took.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

public static class Extension
{
    public static IEnumerable<TSource> TopNWithTies<TSource, TKey>(this IEnumerable<TSource> sequence, Func<TSource, TKey> keySelector, int n) {
        var sequenceDescending = sequence.OrderByDescending(keySelector);
        var topN = sequenceDescending.Take(n);
        TKey cutoff = keySelector(topN.Last());
        var ties = sequenceDescending.Skip(n).TakeWhile(item => keySelector(item).Equals(cutoff));
        return topN.Concat(ties);
    }
}

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Dictionary<string, int> dict = new Dictionary<string, int>();
        dict.Add("AAA", 91);
        dict.Add("BBB", 97);
        dict.Add("CCC", 98);
        dict.Add("DDD", 92);
        dict.Add("EEE", 97);
        dict.Add("FFF", 100);
        
        var top3 = dict.TopNWithTies(kvp=>kvp.Value, 3);
        
        foreach(var kvp in top3){
            Console.WriteLine(kvp.Key + " = " + kvp.Value);
        }
    }
}
```

If instead you want to figure out the rank of every item, you might do something like this, which applies 0-indexed ranks to all the scores. Basically every score gets a rank that is equal to the count of other scores that exceed it.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

public static class Extension
{
    public static IEnumerable<(TSource item, int rank)> RankDescending<TSource, TKey>(this IEnumerable<TSource> sequence, Func<TSource, TKey> keySelector) {
        int rank = 0;
        foreach (var group in sequence.OrderByDescending(keySelector).GroupBy(keySelector))
        {
            foreach (var item in group)
            {
                yield return (item, rank);
            }
            rank += group.Count();
        }
    }
}

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Dictionary<string, int> dict = new Dictionary<string, int>();
        dict.Add("AAA", 91);
        dict.Add("BBB", 97);
        dict.Add("CCC", 98);
        dict.Add("DDD", 92);
        dict.Add("EEE", 97);
        dict.Add("FFF", 100);
        
        var top3 = dict.Rank(kvp=>kvp.Value).TakeWhile(item => item.rank<3);
        
        foreach(var (item, rank) in top3){
            Console.WriteLine(item.Key + " = " + item.Value + " at rank #" + rank);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think an **OrderByDescending** followed by a **TakeWhile** might work.

```
int lastValue=0;
var ordered = dict.OrderByDescending(x=>x.Value);
var result = ordered.TakeWhile((x,index)=>{
    bool takeThis = (index<3)||(x.Value==lastValue);
    lastValue=x.Value;
    return takeThis;
});
```

Fiddle here https://dotnetfiddle.net/JiNgaj